# ‘A, B, and C’ or 'A, B and C'?

Tags: word-usage, punctuation

It seems that the former is US English, while the latter BR English.

What do you native speakers think of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That second comma is not incorrect, it is called the [*Oxford comma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

In most cases, people will omit it, but in certain (formal) contexts, it is used to make sure there is no possible confusion:

> The money will be split between John, Paul, George, and Ringo.
>   The money will be split between John, Paul, George and Ringo.

In the first case everybody gets 1/4 of the money, in the second case it could be argued that John and Paul each get 1/3, while George and Ringo split the remaining third.

If there is no such confusion possible, the comma is usually left out.

Some more interesting reading material on this comma can be found here (Thank you @Laure for the links!)
[What is the Oxford comma?](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/01/video-oxford-comma/)
[Does the Oxford comma increase readability?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63422/does-the-oxford-comma-increase-readability)

Comment: Tow good links [What is the Oxford comma?](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/01/video-oxford-comma/) on the site of Oxford Dictionaries, and [Does the Oxford Comma increase readability?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/63422/41040) on [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/63422/41040).